# IEnumerable is visible in COM, but not ICollection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, com-interop

I have a bunch of Dictionary(Of Integer, SomeClass) in my main class, which I AutoDual for COM use. Users need to iterate over the instances in VBA (Excel specifically), so I have a bunch of these these in my main class...

```
Public ReadOnly Property Inflations() As IEnumerable
    Get
        Return InflationsDict.Values
    End Get
End Property
```

I can use this in my VBA code like this...

```
For Each I In CP.Inflations...
```

But that doesn't support Count. Dictionaries expose ICollection as well, which has .Count, but when I did this single change...

```
Public ReadOnly Property Inflations() As ICollection
```

the method disappears from COM, and that same For Each gets "Run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method." It continues to work fine in VB.net.

I was told the basic rule is that non-generics should export OK. Nothing comes up during the compile - whereas when I tried exporting `IEnumerable(Of Inflation)` on a lark, sure enough a warning comes up in the output.

Is there a sidebar to the rule that applies in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell I've been posting some misleading comments.  The issue you are running into is that the ICollection members will be exposed but its inherited interface (IEnumerable) is not.  Which breaks the ability to iterate the collection.

Let's write an interface for a dictionary.  I'll assume variants:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface IMyDictionary
    ReadOnly Property Count As Integer
    Function Contains(ByVal key As Object) As Boolean
    <DispId(0)> Property Item(ByVal key As Object) As Object
    <DispId(-4)> Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.IEnumerator
End Interface
```

With a sample implementation:

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<ProgId("StackOverflow.Example")> _
Public Class Example
    Implements IMyDictionary

    Private collection As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

    Public Sub New()
        collection = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
        '' Add some sample data
        collection.Add(1, "one")
        collection.Add(2, "two")
        collection.Add(3, "three")
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Count As Integer Implements IMyDictionary.Count
        Get
            Return collection.Count
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IMyDictionary.GetEnumerator
        Return CType(collection.Values, System.Collections.IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()
    End Function

    Public Property Item(ByVal key As Object) As Object Implements IMyDictionary.Item
        Get
            Return collection(CInt(key))
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Object)
            collection(CInt(key)) = CStr(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Function Contains(key As Object) As Boolean Implements IMyDictionary.Contains
        Return collection.ContainsKey(CInt(key))
    End Function
End Class
```

A sample VBScript that exercises it:

```
Set obj = CreateObject("StackOverflow.Example")
WScript.Echo "Count=" & obj.Count
WScript.Echo "Value for key 2=" & obj(2)
WScript.Echo "Contains(3)=" & obj.Contains(3)
WScript.Echo "Contains(42)=" & obj.Contains(42)
WScript.Echo "Values:"
For Each elem in obj
   WScript.Echo "  " & elem
Next
```

Output:

```
Count=3
Value for key 2=two
Contains(3)=True
Contains(42)=False
Values:
  one
  two
  three
```

Comment: Ok, I *think* I understand what is going on here. Luckily I do have a perfect class to attach this to, the dictionaries are actually isolated in a table-like construct that makes this simple. But a question about the inheritance... generally does interface inheritance *not* expose the inherited methods? Or is there a bit of a trick to this?

Comment: There are several problems, but a core one is that there are many COM clients that don't support a coclass with more than one interface.  They can only use the [ComDefaultInterface] and don't have way to ask for another one.  A restriction in scripting languages, VBA, VB6, they have no notion of interfaces at all.  A technical workaround for that is to expose two members, one that returns ICollection and another that return IEnumerable.  Not pretty.

Comment: Which makes me worry that perhaps I was down a blind alley with interfaces in the first place, but I have implemented this and I'm playing around a bit to see what this does to the overall API within the programs that consume it.